# Web Browser and Ubuntu Software not picking up gtk theme

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, gtk

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3, and I tried to switch the default theme to "[this theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1099856/)".
Other than my web browser and the Ubuntu Software application it seems to be quite consistent elsewhere. Can you guys help me in fixing this?

How it looks elsewhere:
[image: How it looks elsewhere]

With Firefox and Ubuntu Software:
[image: With Firefox and Ubuntu Software]